# How to get a flatten dataframe from lists of dictionaries which contain lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, flatten

I'm trying to flat this kind of data structure into a "plain" dataframe.

Raw data is a list of dictionaries, which contain lists.

Data looks like this( reproducible example):

```
data = [{'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[11,12,13,14]}, {'A':[5,6,7,8], 'B':[15,16,17,18]}]
```

My desidered output should be the following pandas dataframe:

```
Out[01]: 
   A   B
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
5  6  16
6  7  17
7  8  18
```

How can i achieve this result?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

```
data = [{'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[11,12,13,14]}, {'A':[5,6,7,8], 'B':[15,16,17,18]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)

   A   B
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
5  6  16
6  7  17
7  8  18
```

Or using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
new = defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        new[k].extend(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(new)

   A   B
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
5  6  16
6  7  17
7  8  18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply generate each DataFrame and concatenate them all:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[11,12,13,14]}, {'A':[5,6,7,8], 'B':[15,16,17,18]}]

df = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(elm) for elm in data), ignore_index=True)
print(df)


   A   B
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
5  6  16
6  7  17
7  8  18
```

Comment: Can also do `df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, data),ignore_index=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [{'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[11,12,13,14]}, {'A':[5,6,7,8], 'B':[15,16,17,18]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

For improve performance use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `extend`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in data:
    for k, v in x.items():
        d[k].extend(v)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
   A   B
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
5  6  16
6  7  17
7  8  18
```

Comment: Coincidence we posted the same approach using `defaultdict`. ;) But why is `df.apply(pd.Series.explode)` is inefficient?

Comment: @Ch3steR - Because pandas function working slowier like pure python here

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly. Should `df.apply` be avoided?

Comment: if u can avoid apply, do so; there is no vectorization in it, and dictionaries have an advantage here for such operations. apply is for all intents and purposes, a wrapper around a for loop. repeated application of series explode will definitely be slower than dicts for this,

Comment: @Ch3steR - I think `explode` here is slowier like pure python strucure like defaultdict here.

Comment: @sammywemmy and jezrael Thank you for the explanation. I'll keep that in mind from now on.